# Error calculating entropy over pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, entropy

I'm trying to calculate the entropy over a pandas series. Specifically, I group the strings in `Direction` as a sequence. Specifically, using this function:

```
diff_dir = df.iloc[0:,1].ne(df.iloc[0:,1].shift()).cumsum()
```

will return the count of strings in `Direction` that are the same until a change. So for each sequence of the same `Direction` string, I want to calculate the entropy of `X,Y`.

Using the code the sequencing of the same string is:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    2
7    2
8    3
9    3
```

This code used to work but it's now returning an error. I'm not sure if this was after an upgrade.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def ApEn(U, m = 2, r = 0.2):

    '''
    Approximate Entropy 

    Quantify the amount of regularity over time-series data.

    Input parameters:
    
    U = Time series
    m = Length of compared run of data (subseries length)
    r = Filtering level (tolerance). A positive number

    '''

    def _maxdist(x_i, x_j):
        return max([abs(ua - va) for ua, va in zip(x_i, x_j)])

    def _phi(m):
        x = [U.tolist()[i:i + m] for i in range(N - m + 1)] 
        C = [len([1 for x_j in x if _maxdist(x_i, x_j) <= r]) / (N - m + 1.0) for x_i in x]
        return (N - m + 1.0)**(-1) * sum(np.log(C))

    N = len(U)

    return abs(_phi(m + 1) - _phi(m))

def Entropy(df):

    '''
    Calculate entropy for individual direction
    '''

    df = df[['Time','Direction','X','Y']]
                                    
    diff_dir = df.iloc[0:,1].ne(df.iloc[0:,1].shift()).cumsum()

    # Calculate ApEn grouped by direction. 
    df['ApEn_X'] = df.groupby(diff_dir)['X'].transform(ApEn)
    df['ApEn_Y'] = df.groupby(diff_dir)['Y'].transform(ApEn)                 

    return df


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50, size = (10, 2)), columns=list('XY'))
df['Time'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)

direction = ['Left','Left','Left','Left','Left','Right','Right','Right','Left','Left']
df['Direction'] = direction


# Calculate defensive regularity
entropy = Entropy(df)
```

Error:

```
return (N - m + 1.0)**(-1) * sum(np.log(C))
ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power
```

Comment: some of the groups after groupby are of size 1, is it expected ?

Comment: Moreover `df['ApEn_X'] = df.groupby(diff_X)['X'].transform(ApEn)` will not work because if you have a group of say size > 1 then the lenght of `df.groupby(diff_X)['X'].transform(ApEn)` will be less then `df` and the assignment will fail.  Can you explain the intention of `diff_X = df.iloc[1:,1].ne(df.iloc[1:,1].shift()).cumsum()` in you code ?

Comment: I've included more detail on this. It measure the length of strings in `Direction` until a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of the below code

```
(N - m + 1.0)**(-1)
```

consider the situation when `N==1` and since  `N = len(U)` this happens when the a group resulted out of groupby will have size of 1. Since `m==2` this end up as

```
(1-2+1)**-1 == 0
```

And we `0**-1` is undefined as so the error.

Now if we look theoretically, how do you define a approximate entropy of a timeseries with just one value; highly unpredictable so it should be as high as possible. For this case let us set it to `np.nan` to denote it is not defined (entropy is always greater then equal to 0)

## code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def ApEn(U, m = 2, r = 0.2):

    '''
    Approximate Entropy 

    Quantify the amount of regularity over time-series data.

    Input parameters:
    
    U = Time series
    m = Length of compared run of data (subseries length)
    r = Filtering level (tolerance). A positive number

    '''

    def _maxdist(x_i, x_j):
        return max([abs(ua - va) for ua, va in zip(x_i, x_j)])

    def _phi(m):
        x = [U.tolist()[i:i + m] for i in range(N - m + 1)] 
        C = [len([1 for x_j in x if _maxdist(x_i, x_j) <= r]) / (N - m + 1.0) for x_i in x]
        if (N - m + 1) == 0:
          return np.nan
        return (N - m + 1)**(-1) * sum(np.log(C))

    N = len(U)

    return abs(_phi(m + 1) - _phi(m))

def Entropy(df):

    '''
    Calculate entropy for individual direction
    '''

    df = df[['Time','Direction','X','Y']]
                                    
    diff_dir = df.iloc[0:,1].ne(df.iloc[0:,1].shift()).cumsum()

    # Calculate ApEn grouped by direction. 
    df['ApEn_X'] = df.groupby(diff_dir)['X'].transform(ApEn)
    df['ApEn_Y'] = df.groupby(diff_dir)['Y'].transform(ApEn)

    return df

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50, size = (10, 2)), columns=list('XY'))
df['Time'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)

direction = ['Left','Left','Left','Left','Left','Right','Right','Right','Left','Left']
df['Direction'] = direction

# Calculate defensive regularity
print (Entropy(df))
```

Output:

```
   Time Direction   X   Y    ApEn_X    ApEn_Y
0     1      Left   6  16  0.287682  0.287682
1     2      Left  22   6  0.287682  0.287682
2     3      Left  16   5  0.287682  0.287682
3     4      Left   5  48  0.287682  0.287682
4     5      Left  11  21  0.287682  0.287682
5     6     Right  44  25  0.693147  0.693147
6     7     Right  14  12  0.693147  0.693147
7     8     Right  43  40  0.693147  0.693147
8     9      Left  46  44       NaN       NaN
9    10      Left  49   2       NaN       NaN
```

Larger sample (which results in 0**-1 issue)

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,50, size = (100, 2)), columns=list('XY'))
df['Time'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
direction = ['Left','Right','Up','Down']
df['Direction'] = np.random.choice((direction), len(df))
print (Entropy(df))
```

Output:

```
    Time Direction   X   Y  ApEn_X  ApEn_Y
0      1      Left  44  47     NaN     NaN
1      2      Left   0   3     NaN     NaN
2      3      Down   3  39     NaN     NaN
3      4     Right   9  19     NaN     NaN
4      5        Up  21  36     NaN     NaN
..   ...       ...  ..  ..     ...     ...
95    96        Up  19  33     NaN     NaN
96    97      Left  40  32     NaN     NaN
97    98        Up  36   6     NaN     NaN
98    99      Left  21  31     NaN     NaN
99   100     Right  13   7     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that when the `ApEn._phi()` function is invoked, it is possible that the specific values for `N` and `m` end up returning a `0`. That then needs to be raised to the negative power of -1, which however is undefined (see also [Why does zero raised to the power of negative one equal infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009868/why-does-zero-raised-to-the-power-of-negative-one-equal-infinity)).

To illustrate, I tried to replicate your scenario specifically, and in the first iteration of the `transform` operation, this is what happens:

```
U is: 1     0
      2    48
```

(the first groupby has 2 elements)

```
N is: 2
m is: 3
```

So effectively when you get to the return value of `_phi()`, you are doing `(N - m + 1.0)**-1 = (2 - 3 + 1)**-1 = 0**-1`, which is undefined. Perhaps the key here is that you say you're groupby by individual direction and passing the `U` array into the Approximate Entropy function, however you're grouping by `diff_X` and `diff_Y` instead, which result in very small groups due to the nature of the method applied. As far as I understand, if you want to calculate the approximate entropy per direction, you simply need to group by 'Direction':

```
def Entropy(df):

    '''
    Calculate entropy for individual direction
    '''           

    # Calculate ApEn grouped by direction. 
    df['ApEn_X'] = df.groupby('Direction')['X'].transform(ApEn)
    df['ApEn_Y'] = df.groupby('Direction')['Y'].transform(ApEn)                 

    return df
```

This results in a dataframe like this:

```
entropy.head()

    Time    Direction   X   Y   ApEn_X      ApEn_Y
0   1       Left        28  47  0.035091    0.035091
1   2       Up          8   47  0.013493    0.046520
2   3       Up          0   32  0.013493    0.046520
3   4       Right       34  8   0.044452    0.044452
4   5       Right       49  27  0.044452    0.044452
```

Comment: Thanks, I am hoping to group via `diff`. Each individual time series of `Direction` is important. If I group by `Direction` overall, the values won't change.

Comment: I see. In that case you'll need to handle the `ZeroDivisionError` as proposed by others.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle your ZeroDivisions. Maybe this way:

```
def _phi(m):
    if N == m - 1:
        return 0
    ...
```

You will then encounter length mismatches on *groupby*s, *df* and *diff_X* has to be of same lengths.

Comment: Do they have to be the same lengths?